# Angular response is undefined

Tags: angularjs

Trying to retrieve using angular the json found at: "https://api.github.com/users/angular", more precisely the id property from that json.
Any thoughts on why this fails (in debug mode I get a

> 'response is not defined'

):

```
<html ng-app="myViewer">
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="MyController">
    {{ result.id }}
    {{ err }}
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("myViewer", []);

    var MyController = function($scope, $http)
    {
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular")
        .then(function1, onerr);

        var function1 = function(response)
        {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        }
        var onerr = function(reason)
        {
            $scope.err = "nightmare";
        }

    }

    app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$http", MyController]);
}());

</script>
</html>
```

I expect the result to be the id that you can see by copying that link in your browser.

Comment: You're naming it MyController, but you have the var as SecondController, incongruity there.

Comment: fixed that was an error when i tried to simplify my code and namings for stackoverflow thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working fiddler **https://jsfiddle.net/paka2/8roj37q9/1/**

```
angular.module("myViewer", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http){
this.result = {};
this.err ;  
         $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular")
        .then(function1, onerr) ;
    function function1 (response)
    {    
      $scope.result = response.data;
    }
    function onerr (reason)
    {
      $scope.err = "nightmare";
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Works if I correct the order:

```
var function1 = function(response)
{
    $scope.result = response.data;
}
var onerr = function(reason)
{
    $scope.err = "nightmare";
}

$http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular")
.then(function1, onerr);
```

function1 should be defined before i call it with then.

Comment: Yes. Function expressions are hoisted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your promise is wrong.

```
  $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/angular').then(function(response){
    $scope.result = response.data;
  })
```

See same HTTP call working below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/8JqZ5NukHnHWGPxZ0GRr

Answer (score 0):

try this i think you have incorrectly defined the controller as mycontroller and it should be SecondController  instead.

```
 app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$http", SecondController ]);
```

Comment: fixed that was an error when i tried to simplify my code and namings for stackoverflow thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with following

var function1 = function(response) { $scope.result = response; }